# Linked tasks in task route assigning (Optaplanner)

Tags: constraints, optaplanner

I'm trying to solve some kind of task route assigning problem with Optaplanner. The task on a user's way can be of a different type. If there occurs a task with the type `lunch_delivery` then there needs to be a task `lunch_pick` before it (`lunch_pick` task always exists in the list of all the tasks).

I'm wondering if I can somehow connect these two tasks as it is necessary that the same user does both the `lunch_pick` and the `lunch_delivery` task (and not that one user would pick the lunch and the other would deliver it).

The current code that doesn't provide a good solution is that the task of type `lunch_pick` has a parameter `linked_task` with an ID of the `lunch_delivery` task. Code in constraint section looks like this:

```
Constraint lunchPickConflict(ConstraintFactory factory) {
        return factory.from(Task.class)
                .filter(task -> task.getVisitType().equals("lunch_pick"))
                .penalize("lunch pick not scheduled good",
                        HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM,
                        task -> task.lunchConflictWeight());
    }
```

The `lunchConflictWeight` function is simple for now and is defined as:

```
public int lunchConflictWeight(){
        int score = 0;
        // we want that lunch pick and lunch delivery are close to each other and that delivery is after pick-up
        Task nextTask = getNextTask();
        while (nextTask != null){
            if (nextTask.visitType.equals("lunch_delivery") && nextTask.getId() == linked_task){
                // this is what we want - we found a task that is connected with our lunch_pick
                break;
            }
            else if(nextTask.visitType.equals("normal")){
                score +=3;
            }
            nextTask = nextTask.getNextTask();
        }
        if (nextTask == null){
            // the lunch pick was the last task or the delivery is done by some other user -> big penal
            score = 100;
        }
        return score;
    }
```

What would be a better solution for this problem? Can I somehow force that `lunch_pick` and `lunch_delivery` would be done by the same user? When I see my results I can easily see that just swapping two tasks between users would bring significant improvement in the score.

+extra question: Is there a way that one constraint would penalize hard in some cases and medium in others?

Answer (score 0):

A) Usually, we don't assign lunch tasks. Instead, we get a shadow variable to delay the start time of the first task after noon by 1 hour. I think I cover it [in the shadow vars video](https://youtu.be/ENKHGBMDaCM).

B) If lunch and lunch_pick are always assigned sequentially to the same user, why not just make them one task?

Comment: A) I edited my text as it wasn't clear enough. It's lunch_delivery which needs to be done. I watched your video and found quite some ideas about Optaplanner - but for this lunch_break I still prefer to write it as a task, because then it can be scheduled in some time hole (it's not determined right from the start).

Comment: B) I couldn't figure out, how to handle the case that these two tasks are done at different locations. +sometimes we have more than one lunch_delivery which makes everything even more complicated (then two lunch_picks are consequent but time in between is 0 as they are done at the same location).

Comment: B) See "auto collapse" pattern for those 2 consequent pickups.

Comment: B) In case these 2 tasks are done at different locations, simply refactor "location" to "arrivalLocation" and "departureLocation". Think of the task a wormhole from the arrival location to the departureLocation and make it have a service time (= the amount of time it takes to complete the task, including transport from arrival to depature location)

Comment: B1) Is this "auto collapse" part of some example? But that double pickup isn't such a big problem as the pick-up task's duration is 0 and if there is another pick-up at the same location the driving time is also 0.

Comment: B2) This wormhole seems a good idea. But it gets complicated if there are more deliveries. Then the pick-ups should be done at the same time (like "auto collapse") but deliveries should be scheduled so that the driving time would be the shortest. But this could be also solved in customer variable listener, right?